# Getting Force close when I try to open my golf scoreboard application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am quite new androids and seem to have came across a Force close on my app and have no idea how to solve it.

Basically a part of my golf app is a scoreboard that the hole the person is on and the amount of strokes taken.

My code works were you have 2 buttons, add and subtract and change the number that shows up in the EditText. A button is then clicked and submits the number into a listview.I'm now trying to get it so that there is 2 add, subtract buttons and edittext and when both numbers have been entered and button to submit is clicked, will show something like 'Your stroke was 2' 'On hole 1'

Here is the code for it

```
package com.uhi.myGolfApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


public class scoreboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button buttonPlus1;
Button buttonMinus1;
EditText editScore1;
Button buttonPlus; 
Button buttonMinus; 
Button buttonOk; 
EditText editScore;
ListView scoreCard;
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Integer score=0;
Integer score1=0;
SharedPreferences prefs;
databaseHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Intent i;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate UI from XML
    setContentView(R.layout.scoreboard);

    // Get a hang of UI components
    buttonPlus1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
    buttonMinus1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsub);
    editScore1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.score1);
    buttonPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    buttonMinus= (Button)findViewById(R.id.subtract);
    buttonOk   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    editScore  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.score);
    scoreCard  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.scorePosted);

    // Add onClick listeners
    buttonPlus1.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMinus1.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonOk.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Get preferences
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editScore.setText( score.toString() );
    editScore1.setText( score1.toString() );


    // Initialize the database
    dbHelper = new databaseHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    // Load the data (essentially executes a SELECT statement)
    cursor = db.query(databaseHelper.tableName, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    // Set the list adapter
    String[] from = {databaseHelper.colStrokes, databaseHelper.colHole};
    int[] to = {R.id.textStroke, R.id.textHole};
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.golfscores, cursor, from, to);
    scoreCard.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
    score = (inState!=null) ? inState.getInt("score",0) : 0;
    score1 = (inState!=null) ? inState.getInt("score1",0) : 0;
    editScore.setText( score.toString() );
    editScore1.setText( score1.toString() );
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("score", score);
    outState.putInt("score1", score1);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View src) {
    switch(src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonadd:
        score1++;
        break;
    case R.id.buttonsub:
        score1--;
        break;
    case R.id.add:
        score++;
        break;
    case R.id.subtract:
        score--;
        break;
    case R.id.enter:
        // Save in DB
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(databaseHelper.colHole, score1);
        values.put(databaseHelper.colStrokes, score);
        db.insert(databaseHelper.tableName, null, values);

        cursor = db.query(databaseHelper.tableName, null, null, null, null, null,     null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        score=0;
        adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        score1=0;
        break;
    }
    editScore.setText( score.toString() );
    editScore1.setText( score1.toString() );
}

}
```

and the database

```
package com.uhi.myGolfApp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class databaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// DB constants
private static final String DB_NAME = "scoreboard.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;    // Schema version

// Schema constants
public static final String tableName  = "scoreboard";
public static final String colHole = "hole";
public static final String colStrokes = "strokes";

// Constructor
public databaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

//create the SQL table and the attributes it will hold
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table "+tableName +
        " (_id integer not null primary key autoincrement, "+
            colHole + " integer, "+ colStrokes+" integer)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

// upgrade the database off the old version 
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

Also I dont know if this is any help but this appears in the LogCat = 'Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'hole' does not exist'

Appreciate any help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that you ran your code once, before you added  the "hole" column, and that is the database that is being read. You need to delete your app's data (Settings -> Applications -> Your app) so that the newest version of the database is created. If you don't have the option to delete data then uninstall it.

Comment: You are a legend! Worked lol. Took a while to figure out how to delete the database but got it in the end. Thanks alot!